# Access questions programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-api

Is there a way to access Google Form questions and response options programmatically from a web app? I would like to use my web app to retrieve this information. I've tried creating a script using Google Apps Script but don't see how I can use that in my React Web App.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675989/http-request-with-oauth2-to-google-app-script-web-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218511/http-request-to-a-function-in-google-scripts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491631/run-google-app-script-from-web-page

Comment: Lot of insightful code for getting around the classroom on Yagisanatode Upload grades into a Google Classroom Coursework Assignment.https://yagisanatode.com/2020/05/13/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/